# Help With TikZ Angle Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tkz-euclide

Is there a way to move the Z angle label so that it is right under the point where  lines XZ and YW meet?  And I also don't want the label to touch the line.

[image: exterior angle of a triangle]

I have tried some of the suggestions on other questions, but most of the time the solution is to make the text smaller, and I don't want to do that.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles, quotes}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate (Y) at (0,0);
\coordinate (X) at (75:4);
\coordinate (Z) at (4,0);
\coordinate (W) at (0:6);
\draw (Y)--(X)--(Z)--cycle--(W);

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](Z,Y,X)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.3](X,Y,Z){Y}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](Y,X,Z)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.3](Z,X,Y){X}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](X,Z,Y)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.3](Y,Z,X){Z}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](W,Z,X)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.3](Z,W,X){W}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you marking it as an angle rather than a point? I don't use Euclide because I don't understand French, but this seems a bit odd.

Comment: I think, you can use tkz Euclide. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide

Comment: @minthao_2011 I don't understand that comment, the OP *is* using `tkz-euclide` (for labels and angle marks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = -0.3](Y,Z,X){Z}
```

by

```
\tkzLabelPoint[below](Z){Z}
```

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-eucl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{
  dimen = m,
  LabelSep = -0.3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.35,-0.38)(6.51,3.4)% boundry found manually
  \pnodes(1,3){X}(0,0){Y}(4,0){Z}(6,0){W}
  \pspolygon(Y)(X)(Z)
  \psline(Y)(W)
  \pstMarkAngle{Z}{Y}{X}{$Y$}
  \pstMarkAngle{Y}{X}{Z}{$X$}
  \pstMarkAngle{X}{Z}{Y}{}
  \pstMarkAngle{W}{Z}{X}{}
  \uput[270](4,0){$Z$}
  \uput[0](6,0){$W$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]